# SQL Server Sum query

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

Today my problem is this I have 2 columns and I wish to check if the sum of those columns isn't bigger than a value (485 for example) and if is do a query...

I though to do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColumnA + ColumnB < 485
```

But it isn't working... I've already tried with

```
SELECT Sum(ColumnA) + Sum(ColumnB) AS Total FROM table
```

but it gives me 1 column with the sum of all rows, I instead want a row for every sum. So how can I do..? xD I hope you understood if not just ask that I try to explain it better! and thanks in advance for those who will help me!

EDIT: I Found out XD the problem was that the columns was Smallint and the result of 1 or more rows was more than 32k so it wasn't working! Thanks all!!

Comment: Why did you tag both `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: Why don't you go finish up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358411/php-check-paypal-payment-and-then-execute-something and then come back here....

Comment: The only reason I can see for your first sql statement to not work is all of your records have ColumnA + ColumnB >= 485.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right query to achieve it is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColumnA+ColumnB<485
```

This way the `Select` will return all the rows where ColumnA + ColumnB is less than 485

If otherwise you want in return the sum of the two columns you can use

```
SELECT SUM(ColumnA)+SUM(ColumnB) FROM Table
```

This way the query do a sum of columnA on all the rows, the sum of ColumnB on all the rows and then sum the two sums...

Answer (score 0):

If you have null values in any of the two columns you have to use `case when`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NULL 0 ELSE ColumnA END) + (CASE WHEN ColumnB IS NULL 0 ELSE ColumnB END) < 485;
```

Maybe you have some null values or all of your data have a greater sum value then 485 for these columns as David Parvin stated.